# Как удалить подобные символы из списка ['\n', '\n']?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Никак не получается удалить эти символы, мне казалось, что генераторы списков должны помочь, но что-то очевидно идет не так, и всё остается на своих местах

```
rus2=[x for x in rus2 if x and x!=['\n']]
```

Comment: Какие "подобные" символы? Приведите примеры входов и выходов, а также отформатируйте код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проверка сравнивает элементы со списком `['\n']`, а не просто с символом `'\n'`.

***Пример:***

```py
li = ['Hello', '\n', 'World!', '\n']

result = [x for x in li if x != '\n']
print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
['Hello', 'World!']
```

Comment: я не знаю нужно ли это Jam, но а если `'Hello\nWorld'`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое! Не могли бы вы ещё, пожалуйста, немного поподробнее рассказать в чём разница между  ['\n'] и '\n', мне как абсолютному новичку не очень понятно это

Comment: @Jam написано же первым предложением -- первое есть список с 1 элементом-строкой `'\n'`, а второе -- просто строка `'\n'`

Comment: @dlm0n ок, ясно

Answer (score 1):

Вариант со скобками тоже можно использовать, но по-другому, применив оператор `in`:

```
li = ['', 'Hello', '\r', '\n', '', 'World!', '\r', '\n']
ch_to_remove = ['\n', '\r']

result = [x for x in li if x and x not in ch_to_remove]
print(result)
```